# Get cell value in another cell based on highest value in column

Tags: arrays, sorting, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want a function that sorts C5:C and D5:D for the biggest value and enters the value of the cell in column B that is on the same row.

I have tried `=sort` and `=filter` but without finding anything that works properly.

[image: My sheet]

Answer (score 1):

I think [SORTN()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7354624) should work for you.

[Here is the documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7354624).

In your specific use case, this should work for you:

```
=SORTN(B5:B,1,0,C5:C,0)
```

and

```
=SORTN(B5:B,1,0,D5:D,0)
```

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
={SORTN(C5:C, 1, 0, D5:D, 0); 
  SORTN(C5:C, 1, 0, E5:E, 0)}
```

[image: 0]